# CakeDC's Users plugin action overriding

Tags: cakephp, cakedc

I have installed CakeDC's Users plugin and I have loaded all the required files in bootstrap.php, as shown below:

```
CakePlugin::load('Users'); // Loads the Users plugin
CakePlugin::load('Search'); // Loads the Search plugin
CakePlugin::load('Utils'); // Loads the Utils plugin
CakePlugin::load('Users', array('routes' => true));
```

I would like to override the add() action of the UsersController of the plugin, so I created the AppUsersController.php file in app/Controller, as instructed here: 
https://github.com/CakeDC/users#extending-the-controller

Then I created an add() action inside the AppUsersController.php, with an empty body, but the original action was not overridden. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Don't create an empty add() on the AppUsersController, because it still load the parent function. Try to copy paste add() from UsersController, and then paste into AppUsersController, then override it

Comment: Same problem. Is it required to override the model and the view as well, or is it ok to override only the controller? Furthermore, should the AppUsersController.php be placed in the app/Controller or in the app/Plugin/Users/Controller folder?

Comment: AppUsersController.php should be place in app/Controller.
More information about AppUsersController at https://github.com/CakeDC/users

The model and View its depends on what you need.